# how to change permissions on SSAS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

I deployed an instance of SQL Server 2012 with SSAS on a server machine. I gave myself administrator rights (during the SQL server install, to my windows account, to Administrator windows account, and to SQL user "sa"); BTW my account is also belongs to the group of Administrator and the SQL Server was installed from my account

When I try to deploy an SSAS project it fails, it tell me. I go into SQL Server Management Studio and -- when I try to manually create a SSAS database -- i am told my account does not have permissions to create a new object.

[image]

After hitting with my head in the wall a few times (and did a few unsuccessful google searches), I logged in with the Administrator account and was able to successfully create a new SSAS database using the SQL Management studio. I go back to my account, and I can't see the database the Administrator created on SSAS (management studio successful connects, but I can't see the new database [no read rights?]).

Does anyone have any idea why my account does not work, and the Administrator account works? And furthermore, how do I fix this permissions issue? (I had looked up the security->logins on the  Database Engine and apparently my account have the same privileges as the Administrator account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect in management Studio to the Analysis Services instance with a user id that has administrative rights on this Analysis Services instance, then you can right-click the instance node, and select Properties/Security to see the users having instance administration rights. Check these and possibly add your account to them.

Also make sure when trying to deploy a project from BIDS that you deploy to the correct server: Right-click the project instance, select Properties/Deployment to check and change these settings.

Comment: Additionally I had to install a "hotfix" because the properties/security was not available
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2889492